# python Regular expression optional match depending on starting letter

Tags: python-2.7, regular-language

I have these two patterns
"R 1 2 3 4 5"
and 
"B 1 2 3 4 5"
I want to create a pattern for both them but only match according to the starting letter.
for example
re.match(r"pattern","R 1 2 3 4 5").groups() ==> (1,none,3,none,5)
while (r"pattern","B 1 2 3 4 5").groups() ==>(none,2,none,4,none)
can anyone help?

Comment: Do you actually want the `None`s in there?

Comment: Preferably not, but I don't know a way to do it without having them there.

Answer (score 0):

The stock `re` module can't do this, but you can do this with [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) which supports variable-length lookbehinds:

```
regex.findall(r"(?<=R.*?)(\d+)\s*\d*\s*|(?<=B.*?)\s*\d+\s*(\d+)", ...)
```

For the `R` case, the output looks like `[('1', ''), ('3', ''), ('5', '')]`, for `B` the output looks like `[('', '2'), ('', '4')]`.

However, you really should just split the string on whitespace and check the first element. This isn't a very nice regex.